# ive got dkim=neutral (bad version) header.i with gmail and dkim=fail (unknown key type) with yahoo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind, exim, dkim

I'm having external ip and ubuntu server with 
exim4.71 and bind9. I'm trying to set valid dkim entry to send mail for gmail

Here are my configuration files:
bind9:

```
_domainkey.example.com.       IN      TXT     "o=-;"
mail._domainkey.example.com.  IN      TXT     "v=DKIM1;k=rsa-sha256;p=MHwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADawAwaAJhAMDO8xXc3fMjQnWs6ejxTsrMa4xvb0470b2wCIbx1/790huhBr1386mkvvzeTpDDwkFmOZWXnJLw+Qeh4p/rkNQ7AVCk2uZQ+Kwy+jxM17QdZaDxSY9U1HYUFXC8BKAUYwIDAQAB"
```

I've got this results from **check-auth@verifier.port25.com**

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

Any idea what the problem is?

from yahoo:

```
from=example.com; dkim=fail (unknown key type)
```

ive change k=rsa-sha256 to just k=rsa and now

```
from=example.com; dkim=pass (ok)
```

This also helped with gmail :)

Solution:

**v=DKIM1;k=rsa-sha256;p=... --> v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=....**

Question solved

Comment: Using dkim-filter or dkimproxy? Can you add t=y to both TXT records, let TTL time out and retry? Also, if you can publish the full headers (with hidden hosts/ips) from google mail?

Comment: t=y its just a test mode. Ive managed to solve this. Ive made a mistake in key declaration. just put k=sha and thats all.

Comment: @lain thanks. Ill be able to do this in 12 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
change dkim field in BIND9 zone:
from `v=DKIM1;k=rsa-sha256;p=...` to --> `v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=....`
rsa-sha256 or rsa-sha1 doesnt work for me :(